# How to modify environment variables using WMI and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, environment-variables, wmi, wmi-query

I need to access an environment variable and modify its value. I can access the variable using WQL ==>

```
wmi.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Environment Where name='Path' And UserName='<System>'");
```

However, I am not sure how to modify and save the value. I am using:

```
var reg = GetObject("winmgmts:/root/cimv2");    
var paths = wmi.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Environment Where name='AA' And UserName='<System>'");
var items = new Enumerator(paths);
var path = items.item();
path.VariableValue = path.VariableValue + ";" + "random";
path.Put_(); //(as per first answer received)
```

But, I get this error:

```
Access denied 
Code 80041003 
Source SWbemObjectEx
```

I have UAC disabled, not sure what to do here.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you change the `VariableValue`, call [`Put_`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393783.aspx) to apply the changes:

```
path.VariableValue = path.VariableValue + ";" + "random";
path.Put_();
```

Comment: I see this:  "Error: Access denied
Code 80041003
Source SWbemObjectEx"

Comment: Evidently this works if we start from admin cmd prompt